# Tzitzis for soldiers

Tags: tzitzis

One of the many incredible intiatives happening during [the war in Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Israel%E2%80%93Hamas_war) is the tying of tzitzis for soldiers of the IDF to wear, specifically those who have either never worn tzitzis before or haven't in a very long time.

Of course this is a beautiful thing. I do wonder though, doesn't that make room for significant aveiros that otherwise wouldn't have happened? The average soldier isn't wearing a four cornered garment and is therefore has no chiyuv to wear tzitzis. By giving them tzitzis, ideally they're doing a mitzvah but if it's tied incorrectly or comes undone won't that lead to an aveira that wouldn't have existed if they didn't have tzitzis at all? Is there concern about this, and would it be reason to try to find a different mitzvah than tzitzis to do for the soldiers?

Comment: It's not common for tzitzis to come undone completely.

Comment: Doesn't this concern apply to everyone always?

Comment: @DoubleAA Of course but in theory the more affilitated people know to either fix or not wear the tzitzis. The purpose of this is to have those who are less affiliated do an easy mitzvah but in doing so it could lead to unknowing aveiros

Comment: I wondered the same about women accidentally lighting shabbos candles too late. But like @DoubleAA said, there's always that potential risk in theory, but I think we're supposed to focus on our obligation in the moment before worrying about what might accidentally go wrong down the road.

Comment: Do you know any other instances of a positive mitzva that we keep by minhag where we say "doing so could lead to more averot so best not"?

Comment: @RabbiKaii wearing tefillin

Comment: @DoubleAA nice. Do any of the principles carry forward here?

Comment: From what I've heard, no one is pushing this on the soldiers: they're asking for it. The morale boost therefore may be a factor in deciding this question.

Comment: @DoubleAA Re: Tefillin - isn't that a mitzvah deoraisa to wear daily? Tzitzis is a minhag that we've taken on, but min hatorah it's a mitzvah only if you're wearing a 4-cornered garment

Comment: I think he means that we limit the time we wear tefillin becaused of concerns about *guf naki*. But I'm not sure it's comparable, because you can still fulfill the mitzvah without wearing them all day.